# i can not insert data in sql tables using foreign key in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

First model class:

```
public class studentinfo
{
            [Key]
            public int StdID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string class_ { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("info")]
            public int InfoID { get; set; }
            public info info { get; set; }
}
```

Second model class:

```
public class info
{
            public int infoID { get; set; }
            public string information { get; set; }
            public ICollection<studentinfo> studentinfo { get; set; }
}
```

Exception thrown

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

I don't know how I can insert data into table and delete or update it please anyone help me.

Comment: Show your code for inserting data to db

Comment: Check inner exception, it will show the column which throws error.

Comment: public ActionResult create(studentinfo stud)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.stud.Add(stud);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("create1");
            }
            return View();
        } i use this code for insertion

Comment: @Berkay what is inner exceptions?